# How to send patch request to firebase with object key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, fetch-api

I am trying to update an entry in a firebase db. I'm learning react and right now my app is very basic but I can't figure out how to do deal with firebase.

When I first add something to my db, my `POST` is like this:

```
fetch('https://shopping******.firebasedatabase.app/shoppinglist.json', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({title, amount}) //this is all I send, like {title: 'Apple', amount: 2}
}).then(response => {
    return response.json()
}).then(responseData => {
    // setShoppingList( prevShoppingList => [...prevShoppingList, {id: responseData.name, title, amount}] );
    dispatch({ type: 'ADD', item: {id: responseData.name, title, amount} }); // I get the new item id from responseData.name
});
```

And this is what firebase gives me as data for my list:

```
{"-NZCS9vSdsK0xFyf7yiQ":{"amount":1,"title":"Apple"}}
```

and then I want to update the amount when I add more of the same item. So I am trying to do a `PATCH` but cannot figure out how to construct the object for the http request body

If I hardcode the data like

```
body: JSON.stringify({"-NZCS9vSdsK0xFyf7yiQ":{"amount":10,"title":"Apple"}})
```

it updates it just fine, but I don't know how to make an object like this.
I tried `const updateItem = {item.id:{amount: item.amount, title: item.title}}`
but it gives me an error: Unexpected token, expected "," where the dot is it item.id

How should I handle this?

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: If you want to use a string as an object's key, you have to wrap it in square brackets, something like this: `{[item.id]:{amount: item.amount, title: item.title}}`